# Want to fetch value of a tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html on a page like this:

```
    <div id="headline" class="editable-item"><p class="title"  dir="ltr">InfosysSolutions Pvt. Ltd.</p></div>
```

The value in paragraph tag changes every time. I want too fetch value inside this tag ie: in this case it is "InfosysSolutions Pvt. Ltd." using javascript.

Comment: use jQuery..$ (selector).text();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the contents of the `p` element with class `title` inside the `#headline` element

```
var title = document.querySelector('#headline .title').innerHTML
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/47u3ch3v/)